# Git username is inconsistent with gitlab -error

Tags: git, terraform, gitlab, devops

When I am trying to perform git push in my remote branch I am getting the following error.

```
Your git username is inconsistent with gitlab account name.
```

I have tried with the git config commands and also reconfiguring the credentials but it did not work. Any solution for the above error in Visual studio code IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the [commit check](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/v16.3.4-ee/ee/spec/lib/ee/gitlab/checks/push_rules/commit_check_spec.rb#L336-358) [push rule](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/v16.3.4-ee/ee/lib/ee/gitlab/checks/push_rules/commit_check.rb#L87-103).

Use `git config --local user.name "…"` and/or [your profile settings](https://gitlab.com/-/profile/) to make the names match. Or discuss with your team wether that rule needs to be active ;-)